# Change mime type for html files under certain path

Tags: apache, mime-types, cdn, akamai

we are having an issue with our CDN billing us for page views and they are considering all text/html mime types as an html page and a page view. however, we actually have java (jsp's) that are obviously text/html which do relate to a page view but we also have small .html files which get loaded by javascript into the page for dynamic content which is business controlled. I quick dirty way to fix the billing without having to go rewrite the whole contract with the vendor would be to change the mime type for the html files under a certain directory to something other then text/html. I was going to do with by editing the apache config. I a few question i have for this is:

1) What if i change the mime type to text/plain or something else for these files? is there any impact of doing this? 
2) Is there any other valid html mime type thats nots text/html? I assume no.
3) Any other ideas to fixing this issue?

**UPDATE**
I was thinking about changing the html file to be served as application/javascript. What is the impact of doing this? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What if i change the mime type to text/plain or something else for these files? is there any impact of doing this?

If you change the mime type, the browser will not render it properly.

> 2) Is there any other valid html mime type thats nots text/html? I assume no.

[SSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009162/ssi-vs-jsp-difference):

```
AddType text/x-server-parsed-html .shtml .sht 
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .sht
```

> 3) Any other ideas to fixing this issue?

Convert the small HTML files into [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631369/ajax-vs-ahah-is-there-a-performance-advantage) or [XHTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1079375/1113772).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure akamai is charging you based on pageviews and not on bandwidth utilized ? You may want to talk to your akamai contact on this.